# Python; Linked list and traversing!

Tags: python, linked-list, traversal

Starting some programming with python at school now, and I don't know how to proceed with this problem. Any thoughts?

Input consists of integer separated by line breaks. Your program should submit them in a linked list, traverse the linked list and print the highest number.

Something to take the first number, and do an action which says "if the next number is bigger, take that one, else, keep the current number, and head down the list and repeat"

Then when it gets to the end of the list, it prints the value it has.

```
from sys import stdin

class Kubbe:
    vekt = None
    neste = None
    def __init__(self, vekt):
        self.vekt = vekt 
        self.neste = None 

def spor(kubbe):
    # WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
    # Creates linked list
    forste = None
    siste = None
    for linje in stdin:
        forrige_siste = siste
        siste = Kubbe(int(linje))
        if forste == None:
            forste = siste
        else:
            forrige_siste.neste = siste

# Calls the solution function and prints the result
print spor(forste)
```

Input: example

```
54
37
100
123
1
54
```

Required output

```
123
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't realise I only knew *english* python.

Comment: please fix the indentation and use *english* variable names

Comment: @Nick, why should english names be required?  Python 3 even goes to the trouble of allowing identifiers containing _any_ alphabetic unicode character (and, thus, names in Chinese, Vietnamese, Korean, Arab, ...)...!-)

Comment: @Nick I hope he's using only ASCII as well, because if he's using any accented letters...

Comment: @Alex, to make the code -supposedly- more readable, assuming the majority of SO users grok english.

Comment: @Nick, I guess that, since English isn't my native language anyway, I don't have any more problem with `forste` than with `first`, `vekt` vs `weight`, `neste` vs `next`, `linje` vs `line` -- the pairs of words being much more obviously close to each other than either is to either of my native language, Italian, or the first foreign one I learned, French.  If they were in ideograms, or even just a Slavic language, or Arab, I'd have much more trouble of course!-)

Answer (score 6):

"Linked lists" are rarely used in Python -- normally, one uses just `list`, the Python built-in list, which is actually more of a "dynamic vector".  So, it's peculiar to see a linked list specified as part of the exercise's constraints.

But the main point is, the code you're showing is *already* creating a linked list -- the head is at `forste`, and, for each node, the next-node pointer at `.neste`, the payload at `.vekt`.  So, presumably, that's not what you're asking about, no matter the text of your question.

The simple way to loop through your linked list once you have fully constructed it (i.e., at the end of the current code for `spor`) is

```
current = forste
while current is not None:
   ...process current.vekt...
   current = current.neste
```

In your case, the logic for the "process" part is of course, as your Q's text already says:

```
   if current.vekt > themax:
       themax = current.vekt
```

The only subtlety is, you need to initially set `themax`, before this `while` loop to "the lowest possible number"; in recent versions of Python, "minus infinity" is reliably recorded and compared (though only as a float, it still compares correctly to ints), so

```
themax = float('-inf')
```

would work.  More elegant might be to initially set the maximum to the first payload, avoiding messing with infinity.

Comment: Also probably it is useful for spor to have return statement and forste to have global value... and of course kubbe to actually be used or the parameter removed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer based on your own code and language. Sorry if the new variable and function names do not translate well, as I don't speak Norwegian ([Google Language Tools](http://www.google.com/language_tools) is my friend).

**Comment**: Like airplane Air Traffic Control the default language of most international programming forums such as StackOverflow is English. If you use it, you are likely to get quicker, better, and more answers -- and it probably makes the question and related answers useful to the largest number of other folks. Just my 2 øre... ;-)

```
from sys import stdin

class Kubbe:
    vekt = None
    neste = None
    def __init__(self, vekt):
        self.vekt = vekt
        self.neste = None

def spor():
    # WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
    # Creates linked list
    forste = None
    siste = None
    while True:
        try:
            linje = raw_input()
        except EOFError:
            break
        forrige_siste = siste
        siste = Kubbe(int(linje))
        if forste == None:
            forste = siste
        else:
            forrige_siste.neste = siste
    return forste

def finne_maksimal(lenketliste):
    storste = None
    if lenketliste is not None:
        storste = lenketliste.vekt
        gjeldende = lenketliste.neste
        while gjeldende is not None:
            if gjeldende.vekt > storste:
                storste = gjeldende.vekt
            gjeldende = gjeldende.neste
    return storste

lenketliste = spor()
storste = finne_maksimal(lenketliste)
if lenketliste is None:
    print "tom liste"
else:
    print "storste er", storste
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin function in Python called `reduce`, which traverses a list and "compresses" it with a given function. That is, if you have a list of five elements `[a,b,c,d,e]` and a function `f`, it will effectively do

```
temp = f(a,b)
temp = f( temp, c )
...
```

You should be able to use this to write a very neat solution.

If you want to be less abstract, you will need to iterate over each element of the list in turn, storing the greatest number so far in a variable. Change the variable only if the element you have reached is greater than the value of said variable.

Comment: How is `reduce(max, sequence)` preferable to just `max(sequence)`?

Comment: @Alex: Oh, I assumed he was going to write his own pairwise `max`. Clearly `max(sequence)` is better Python.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with your input (works in both python 2 and 3). Notice how max works with duck typing of Python!

This version works with Python3 also from file.

```
import sys
class Kubbe:
    vekt = None
    neste = None
    def __init__(self, vekt):
        self.vekt = vekt 
        self.neste = None 

def spor():
    # WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
    # Creates linked list
    forste = None
    siste = None
    while True:
        linje = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
        if not linje:
            break

        forrige_siste, siste = siste, Kubbe(int(linje))
        if forste is None:
            forste = siste
        else:
            forrige_siste.neste = siste
    return forste

def traverse(linkedlist):
    while linkedlist is not None:
        yield linkedlist.vekt
        linkedlist=linkedlist.neste

# Calls the solution function and prints the result
linkedlist=spor()

for item in traverse(linkedlist):
    print(item)

# use builtin max:
print('Maximum is %i' % max(traverse(linkedlist)))
# if not allowed:
m = linkedlist.vekt
for item in traverse(linkedlist.neste):
       if item > m:  m = item 
print(m)
```

Comment: This was close, but it seems like it only prints out the first number, regardless of the value. What do you think?

Comment: Gives me 123. Did you run it?

Comment: Yeah I runned it, it gave me the first number in the .txt file. I changed the numbers, more than one time to be shure.

Comment: It works with typed in values from keyboard. stdin gave me errors of RPCProxy. I changed to while loop.

Comment: I tested it as you said and indeed it works. Just not with the txt file

Answer (score 0):

The below code would work. The `Node` class represents the `LinkedList` Node. The LinkedList class defines the methods to add node at the end of the Linked List and `find_max` will traverse through the list and return the node with largest key.

```
   class Node(object):
        def __init__(self, key, next_node):
            self.key = key 
            self.next_node = next_node

    class LinkedList(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.head = None

        def append(self, key):
            # Create a new Node
            new_node = Node(key, None)
            if (self.head == None):
                self.head = new_node
            else:
                tmp = self.head
                while(tmp.next_node != None):
                    tmp = tmp.next_node
                tmp.next_node = new_node

        def find_max(self):
            tmp = self.head
            max_num = 0 
            while(tmp != None):
                if (tmp.key > max_num):
                    max_num = tmp.key
                tmp = tmp.next_node
            return max_num
```